# javascript-report error if user enter time beyond 24-hour

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The end time cannot be beyond 5:59 AM like Start of "22:00" and a finish of "13:00" as this would be impossible.
24-hour period is from(6:00 AM - 5:59 AM)
How to get the solution..Please help

```
 var ms = document.getElementById("<%= txtmonstart.ClientID %>").value;
    var me = document.getElementById("<%= txtmonend.ClientID %>").value;

 var start = ms.substring(0, ms.indexOf(":"));
    var end = me.substring(0, me.indexOf(":"));

     if (end >= 6 && start < end || start < 6 && end >= 6) {
        alert("The end time for a shift cannot be beyond 5:59 AM. Please split this shift  accordingly.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is not quite right (since both sides are essentially identical - if the right side is true, the left side must be too), and you didn't parenthesise correctly. Try this:

```
if( end >= 6 && (start > end || start < 6))
```

Also note that you should run `start` and `end` through `parseInt(...,10)` first, otherwise you will find that `12 < 2`.